# why form_for rails is generating action: 'show'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I'm generating a form with `form_for` in Rails as follows:

```
# Controller
def new
  @species = Specie.new
  render partial: 'maintainers/species/new'
end

# In _new.html.erb
<%= render 'maintainers/species/form', species: @species %>

# In maintainers/species/form
<%= form_for(species, html: {remote: true, id: 'species_form'}) do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

but I get this error:

`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"species"} missing required keys: [:id]`

What could be happening?

Comment: Does this occur after you click submit?

Comment: No, this occur when the partial is charging, creating the form.

Comment: There is a typo in your code: `@species = Specie.new` should be `@species = Species.new`. Not sure if that is the problem.

Comment: There is no id generated when you instantiate a Species. That's your problem

Comment: @TomAranda I've generated this with Scaffold and the Specie Object is working fine in another places.

Comment: Makes sense if this was generated with scaffolding.   It does not always get plurals and singulars correct.  This is probably not a typo then.

Comment: @Cyzanfar, true...but why is that route being requested in the first place?

Comment: @DiegoPatricioAguilefSánchez, can you run `bundle exec rake routes | grep specie` in the command line and post the results?

Comment: @Cyzanfar There is no ID because the Object has been just initialized and this should generate the url with 'new path' ( /species/new ) not 
 'show path' (/species/:id)

Comment: @TomAranda  https://pastebin.com/yCs6FR4F  here is my routes

Comment: Your routes look fine.  This one is stumping me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a POST request to call the create action:

```
# In maintainers/species/form
<%= form_for(species, html: {remote: true, , method: :post, id: 'species_form'}) do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Notice the `method: :post` parameter.

By default, *form_for* will issue a GET request, which maps to show action in Rails.

Comment: That should be a solution, but form_for generates the 'method' automatically depending of the object that have passed, in this case generates method 'POST', cause the object has been  only initialize, another case is when the Object have one record like Object.find(1) what is used in the edit action and generathed the 'PATCH' method. Now, I'm usign this form partial  in both cases and causes me problems